# PHP Curl Request - Diawi API

Tags: php, curl, diawi

I'm struggling to get my Curl request working. The aim of the code is to upload a file to diawi.com using their API. This is my first attempt at using curl, I'm unsure of the correct syntax.

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://upload.diawi.com/',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: multipart/form-data"
    ),
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        token => 'token',
        file => 'http://example.com/apps/myapp.ipa',
        find_by_udid => 0,
        wall_of_apps => 0,
        callback_url => 'http://www.example.com/apps/diawi_response.php',
        callback_email => 'me@company.com'
    )
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;
```

At the moment the response I'm getting is "No file uploaded".

Here is the example request from the documentation:

```
$ curl https://upload.diawi.com/ -F token='TOKEN' \
-F file=@MyApp.ipa \
-F find_by_udid=0 \
-F wall_of_apps=1 \
-F password='installation password' \
-F comment='Comment on the build' \
-F callback_url='http://www.example.com/my-diawi-callback-url' \
-F callback_email='me@company.com'
```

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Test token: MrdS5g9MpZhKn8jlJNuANRlmPuSBkBxWX1LTIptn8p

Test file: http://defu.se/ESFileExplorer.apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this source.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $url = "https://upload.diawi.com/"; 
    $filename = realpath('./ESFileExplorer.apk');
    if ($filename != '')
    {
        $headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"); // cURL headers for file uploading
        $postfields = array(
            "token"             => 'YOUR-TOKEN',
            "file"              => new CurlFile( $filename ),
            "find_by_udid"      => 0,
            "wall_of_apps"      => 1,
            "callback_email"    => 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
        ); // cURL options
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        curl_exec($ch);
        if(!curl_errno($ch))
        {
            // echo $ch;
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            if ($info['http_code'] == 200)
                $errmsg = "File uploaded successfully";
            // print_r($info);
        }
        else
        {
            $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        $errmsg = "Please select the file";
    }
    echo $errmsg;
?>
```

Result I got

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Vary: Accept-Encoding Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Tue, 26 Jul 2016 19:40:33 GMT Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000 {"job":"U37Nq7ta3Q711AsbvYrODFfvTLoyNwY4XslCFI7oV0"}File uploaded successfully

[image]

Comment: Hey dude, sorry for my delay in replying! I've added a token and a file to use for testing in the bottom of my question.

Comment: @d.abyss Can you send me link of document?

Comment: @d.abyss Hi bro. I had update my answer. Working now. xD

Comment: Got correct response! :) I noticed however the response doesn't contain the link - need to query `$ curl -vvv 'https://upload.diawi.com/status?token=TOKEN&job=identifierOfYourUploadJob'` when getting success on this first query. The identifier is from this first response we got here.

Comment: You can add new curl php with your job got from my source. It's easy. @d.abyss. Because I had turn off my computer.

Comment: @d.abyss Are you finish it? xD

Comment: Hi, yes I did finish it. The second query uses GET and was much simpler.